# Absolute convergence of series question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

> Let $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ be absolutely convergent series of complex numbers. For each $n \in N$, set $c_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n$ is absolutely convergent and that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n = (\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n )(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_n )$

I'm not familiar with complex analysis (although I imagine the proof here doesn't really revolve around the series being complex). I think I can understand the second part, as each term in $(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 +...)(b_0 + b_1 + b_2 +...)$ will appear exactly once in $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n$
However, what is the easiest way of showing that the series converges in the first place? It's been a good while since I've done analysis so all help is appreciated!

Comment: See Merten's Thm proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: Roughly speaking, it’s because you can embed every right-angled triangle into a square (and vice versa), so you can directly compare $\sum_{n=0}^N \lvert c_n\rvert $ to $(\sum_{n=0}^N \lvert a_n\rvert) (\sum_{n=0}^N \rvert b_n\vert)$.